# Convert 2 DataTable to Netsed JSon Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, datatable, json.net

I have 2 Datatables which I get from database and fill them like this

```
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
 DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

   MySqlDataReader sdr;
   using (MySqlConnection Conn = new MySqlConnection(dbConn))
   {
       Conn.Open();
       using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Query 1", Conn))
       {
          // Filtering 
           sdr = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
           dt1.Load(sdr);
       }
       using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("Select Query 2", Conn))
       {
          // Filtering 
           sdr = myCmd.ExecuteReader();
           dt2.Load(sdr);
       }
       sdr.Close();
       Conn.Close();
   }
```

`dt1` returns 1 row of data while `dt2` returns nrows of data.

Sample Data For `td1` will be like this

```
 Column1        Column2         columnN
 ---------------------------------------------
 ColumnValue    ColumnValue     ColumnValue
```

Sample Data For `td2` will be like this

```
 Column1        Column2         columnN
 ---------------------------------------------
 ColumnValue    ColumnValue     ColumnValue
 ColumnValue    ColumnValue     ColumnValue
 ColumnValue    ColumnValue     ColumnValue
 ...........    ............    ............
```

Now my Goal is to convert these 2 datatables into a `nested json object` like this

```
 Data = {
   "dt1":{
         "Column1":"Value",
         "Column2":"Value",
         "ColumnN":"Value"
       },
    "dt2":[
       {
         "column1":"Value",
         "column2":"Value",
         "columnN":"Value"
       },
       {
         "Column1":"Value",
         "Column2":"Value",
         "ColumnN":"Value"
       },
           ...... and so on
      ]
}
```

just to be clear, These `Data` will be use in Dashboard hence its coming from differen tables via `Subqueries` example column in `dt1` will be like `Total Users`, `Active Users`, etc. and example column in `dt2` will be like Activities by User, etc.

I have tried String builder( which I think is the solution) and JavaScript serilizer like [this Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9bff34/3-ways-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Your question needs to be clear.  "dt1 returns 1 value for each row" but  in your nested json it shows only 1 row with differrent columns. Can you show dt1 and dt2 data after you got it from db pls ?

Comment: I mean  `dt1` is one object while  `dt2 is list object`, I will add a sample data for both

Comment: I added Sample data both borh `'Datatables`. dt1 is granted to return 1 row of data while dt2 will return Nrows of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is absolutely unclear from your question what type you want, but if you want c# classes

```
Data data = new Data { dt1 = JArray.FromObject(dt1)[0].ToObject<L<Dt1>(), 
                       dt2 = JArray.FromObject(dt2).ToObject<List<Dt2>>() };

public class Data
{
    public Dt1 dt1 { get; set; }
    public List<Dt2> dt2 { get; set; }
}

public class Dt1
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string ColumnN { get; set; }
}

public class Dt2
{
    public string column1 { get; set; }
    public string column2 { get; set; }
    public string columnN { get; set; }

}
```

or if you need just a json string, you don't need any classes

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { dt1 = JArray.FromObject(dt1)[0], dt2 = dt2 });
```

or JObject

```
JObject jObj = JObject.FromObject(new { dt1 = JArray.FromObject(dt1)[0], dt2 = dt2 });
```

Comment: I will be first converting it into just object as above and then will use that in frontend, probably retrivig it from the json object. The json object will be use by Web & Mobile versions hence, an API end which returns json object. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: any difference between the `json string` and the `json object`?. I see they both return same exact data format

Comment: @AbdifatahA It is the same differense as between DateTime.Now and DateTime.Now.ToString().  Dt1 as a list  you are asking in your question. I can not see your  API code so I don't know what response you are creating